# Regular expression for email which should contain hyphen in between but not at the starting and ending position

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression which is satisfying the condition but it is allowing hyphen at the beginning. How to restrict at the beginning. I want the same regular expression with restriction of hyphen at the beginning as it is allowing some other characters which I required.

```
/^[A-Z0-9-._%+]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[A-Z-]+[A-Z]+` I think, where A-Z is whatever character set you want to allow.  Just require at least one non- dash character at the beginning and end of what your current expression is.

Comment: email validation is not so simple. On the other hand, it is a well-known issue. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: Email validation via regex is impossible I think, but his narrow question - "How do I exclude a dash at the beginning or end" is pretty well scoped. @DrPhil

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
public class QuickyTest{

   static String[] testVectors = { "alaskjf", 
                          "o-kay@example.com",
                                 "-dash@x.AA", 
                                 "dash-@y.ZZ" };

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(?i:[A-Z0-9._%+]+|[A-Z0-9._%+]+[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[A-Z0-9._%+]+@([A-Z0-9-]+.)+[A-Z]{2,4})" );
      for( String test : testVectors ) {
         Matcher match = pattern.matcher( test );
         System.out.println( test + " : " + match.matches() );
      }
   }

}
```